# CMake error while running flutter desktop application

Tags: flutter, cmake

When I am trying to launch flutter desktop application, this error occurred to me:

> "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
>
> Generator
>
> Visual Studio 16 2019
>
> could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
>
> Building Windows application...
>
> Exception: Unable to generate build files"

**What I did...**

**1- Installed Visual Studio 2022 with (Desktop development with C++ and Universal Windows Platform development)**

**2- Run these commands:**

> flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
>
> flutter create .
>
> flutter run -d windows

Also I tried to use dev channel:

> flutter channel dev
>
> flutter upgrade
>
> flutter config--enable-windows-uwp-desktop

And these what I have when I run **flutter devices** and **flutter doctor**

**flutter devices**

> 4 connected devices:
> Windows (desktop)       • windows • windows-x64     • Microsoft
> Windows [Version 10.0.22000.318] Windows (UWP) (desktop) • winuwp  •
> windows-uwp-x64 • Chrome (web)            • chrome  • web-javascript
> • Google Chrome 94.0.4606.81 Edge (web)              • edge    •
> web-javascript  • Microsoft Edge 95.0.1020.44

**flutter doctor**

> [√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.6.0-11.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows
> [Version 10.0.22000.318], locale en-US)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 31.0.0)
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
>
> [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022
> 17.0.0)
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.61.1)
>
> [√] Connected device (4 available)
>
> • No issues found!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*3rd Feb 2022 Update: The latest version of Flutter, version 2.10 stable, has this issue fixed along with stable desktop support for Windows.*

*Update: The flutter beta channel (2.9.0-0.1.pre onwards) comes with a fix.*

According to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85922) on the main flutter repo, Flutter prior to version 2.9 does not support Visual Studio 2022. If you want to build while targeting Windows you'll either have to install VS 2019 alongside 2022 or [use this workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85922#issuecomment-953454095):

> The current workaround is : download your appropriate flutter version,
> edit _cmakeVisualStudioGeneratorIdentifier in
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/windows/build_windows.dart#L25-L28
> to your appropriate CMake Visual Studio Generator. You can get the
> currently available CMake Visual Studio Generators on this page :
> https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#id13.
>
> By default the _cmakeVisualStudioGeneratorIdentifier comes with CMake
> Visual Studio 2019 Generator. If you are going to use CMake Visual
> Studio 2022 Generator - firstly ensure your visual studio 2022
> distribution contains Cmake 3.21 or later, refer
> https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2017%202022.html
> for details.

To apply these changes on Windows:

- Edit `path\to\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\windows\build_windows.dart`, and change the constant on line 28 from `'Visual Studio 16 2019'` to `'Visual Studio 17 2022'`
- Delete `flutter_tools.stamp` and `flutter_tools.snapshot` in `path\to\flutter\bin\cache\` (to cause flutter to regenerate its build tools with the new source code you changed above)
- In the project path, run `flutter clean` to remove cached CMake files referring to the wrong Visual Studio version
- In the project path, run `flutter run -d windows` to restart the build (successfully, this time)

Answer (score 12):

1. Download [Visual Studio 17 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes)
2. Delete **CMakeLists.txt** from project (path: your_prject_name/windows/CMakeLists.txt)
3. Run in terminal `flutter clean`
4. Then run `flutter create .`

Comment: Thk for saving my ass

Answer (score 2):

In my case only running `flutter clean && flutter pub` gets the issue resolved..

Comment: Missing subcommand for "flutter pub".

Comment: `flutter clean && flutter pub get` - same error after running this command in android studio

Comment: after this, you have to run 'flutter pub get'.

Answer (score 1):

Go  flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/windows and open build_windows.dart file and on line 24 change:

```
 const int kCurrentUwpTemplateVersion = Visual Studio 17 2022;
```

Save the file and run flutter. Select the windows device. It will run fine by now without any errors .

Comment: this hack no longer works (if it worked at all) in version 3.3.10, the file does not contain a kCurrentTemplateVersion variable

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution
flutter is looking for app.so file in project_folder\build\windows\runner\Debug\data\app.so;
but the app.so file is actually in project_folder\build\windows\runner
to fix the problem just move app.so file from project_folder\build\windows\runner\ to project_folder\build\windows\runner\Debug\data\ and it will work

Answer (score 1):

I had this error many time now and i tried everything but one thing that solved it for me, was moving the flutter project highter up in the windows file structure, because windows (and apparently cmake) has problems creading or writing binaries too far down.

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the windows sdk then reinstalling it at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the

> `lib/main.dart`

file and just recreate the flutter project by running this command in PowerShell to any directory you like:

```
flutter create chatapp
```