# Flutter error Exception: Unable to generate build files for windows desktop app

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, cmake

My desktop which has Windows 11 did an update of Windows while I left the computer unattended. Now suddenly I get this error Exception: Unable to generate build files on my app that worked perfectly before. I don't get any additional information about the error.

I get no problems from flutter doctor.

I see several posts about this error but I've tried the available solutions and nothing seems to work. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Visual C++ Redistributable, and did the same with C++ on my Visual Studio IDE, I deleted and recreated the Windows directory in my project.

I've seen people mention CMake regarding this problem. I tried to run my CMake.exe and got an error that MSVCP140.DLL can't be found. But shouldn't uninstalling and reinstalling Visual C++ Redistributable take care of said problem?

Also tried these solutions

[CMake error while running flutter desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69944913/cmake-error-while-running-flutter-desktop-application)

However, the top answer seems to be obsolete as there are no constant for me to change in build_windows.dart.

EDIT:
I managed to solve it, seems the Windows update deleted both msvcp140.dll and msvcp140_1.dll so I took both from a friend's computer and copied them to my machine.